# Error while running a new created React JS app in WebStorm

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webstorm

I have just created a new web app using WebStorm; it comes with a template and I haven't added any new code, but when I try to run it it shows this Error:

```
 "E:\WebStormData\WebStorm 2017.2.2\bin\runnerw.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" --debug-brk=4096 --expose_debug_as=v8debug F:\MyApps\myapp\src\index.js
Debugger listening on [::]:4096
F:\MyApps\myapp\src\index.js:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import React from 'react';
                                                              ^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
    at createScript (vm.js:56:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:97:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:542:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Timeout.Module.runMain [as _onTimeout] (module.js:604:10)
    at ontimeout (timers.js:386:14)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:250:5)
```

**My `index.js`.**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

**My `App.js`**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h2>Welcome to React</h2>
        </div>
        <p className="App-intro">
          To get started, edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

**My `App.test.js`**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h2>Welcome to React</h2>
        </div>
        <p className="App-intro">
          To get started, edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

**Some one with WebStorm experience to help me out with this.**

Comment: Please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). How do you expect us to help you fix your problem if you don't show us any code?

Comment: @stybl, have you  ever used Webstorm , it automatically generates codes, like a simple template when you initially create a  new project, so  i haven't added anything but it crashes with that error

Comment: I'll suggest you to read well questions

Comment: try using require instead of import for node. const React = require('react'); Use Create React App to get started with react app.

Comment: @Etherealm, am not getting you  but let me try to update my with post index.js and App.js

Comment: guide me please with those codes i think thats where theres the problem

Comment: did you see my initial code which comes @Eherealm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error message I can see that you are trying to run your React component with **Node.js**. Strange idea. React applications are run in browser, this is a client-side code, so you have to build your application, start the server it is hosted on (in applications created using **File | New | Project... | React App**, you should normally run `npm run start` to build the app and start dev server) and then run/debug it in browser using [JavaScript Debug](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2017.3/run-debug-configuration-javascript-debug.html) Run configuration.

Please see https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2017/01/debugging-react-apps/ for more information about debugging react apps in WebStorm