# Cannot run a React app with WebStorm

Tags: node.js, reactjs, intellij-idea, webstorm

I am totally new to React and I am trying to follow the examples on [react official website](https://reactjs.org/community/examples.html).

While running the calculator app(index.js) using WebStorm OR intellij idea ultimate

[**output of npm run start or npm start**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OxNsn.png)

And i get this error:

```
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import React from 'react';
                                                              ^^^^^^
    SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
        at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
        at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
        at Module._compile (module.js:599:28)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:646:10)
        at Module.load (module.js:554:32)
        at tryModuleLoad (module.js:497:12)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:489:3)
        at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:676:10)
        at startup (bootstrap_node.js:187:16)
        at bootstrap_node.js:608:3

    Process finished with exit code 1
```

My question is how to run such  an app using intellij idea ultimate What i tried:

```
npm install -g create-react-app
npm install -g eslint
npm install --save-dev babel-preset-es2015
npm install --save-dev babel-core babel-preset-es2015 babel-preset-react
npm install -g eslint babel-eslint eslint-plugin-react eslint-plugin-import eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y eslint-plugin-flowtype
```

And adding the following to package.json:

```
"babel": {
  "presets": [ "es2015", "react" ]
}
```

Or to .babelrc

```
{
  "presets": [ "es2015", "react" ]
}
```

My question is how to run such  an app using intellij idea ultimate package.json

```
{
  "name": "emoji-search",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "homepage": "http://ahfarmer.github.io/emoji-search",
  "devDependencies": {
    "gh-pages": "^1.1.0",
    "react-scripts": "^1.0.17"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "github-fork-ribbon-css": "^0.2.1",
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "./node_modules/react-scripts/config/eslint.js"
  },
  "babel": {
    "presets": [ "es2015", "react" ]
  }
}
```

(My question is how to run such  an app using intellij idea ultimate )

Comment: Are you starting your application with `npm start`?

Comment: No with webStrom

Comment: Can you share your package.json file

Comment: Running `npm start` should start you react app correctly. If you don't want to run command in the terminal, you can refer to my answer.

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46690350/error-while-running-a-new-created-react-js-app-in-webstorm

Comment: @lena Thanks for your down-voting. I did everything your wrote on the other post but i get this error :   This site can’t be reached
localhost refused to connect.
Did you mean http://localhost3000.org/?
Search Google for localhost 3000
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Comment: Dev server run with `react-scripts start` (`npm start`) normally listens on `localhost:3000` (https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app). ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED usually indicates that the server has not been started. Did you start it?

Comment: npm start gives errors. Please check my post (output of npm run start or npm start)

Comment: Can you add all of your npm error output when running npm start, including the logs?   @lena This is not a duplicated question

Comment: console output indicates that `react-scripts` module is likely not installed. What did you do exactly to make sample apps work? Normally all you need is following the instructions in readme: clone/download the application, install dependencies by running `npm install` in project root dir, then use `npm start` to start the server. No need to add anything to package.json, etc. Installing create-react-app, babel presets, etc. is also not required (moreover, adding extra babel modules/configs may break existing configuration).

Comment: I'd suggest deleting all projects you have installed, downloading them from scratch and then just following the instructions

Comment: from npm output: `Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to install?`. You didn't run `npm install` in project root dir, did you?

Answer (score 4):

You can install react-scripts like this `npm install --save-dev react-scripts`.
Then you will be able to run this command: `react-scripts start` at the root of your project (where package.json is).

If you don't want to use command, you can follow this tutorial on [How to run a React app with Webstorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/react.html#react_running_and_debugging)

Basically, to start a react app, you need to run a command (`npm start`); If you want to use the webstorm start button, you need to bind it to the command. From this [link](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/npm.html):

1. Choose Run | Edit Configuration on the main menu.
2. Click add on the toolbar and select npm from the pop-up list.
3. In the Run/Debug Configuration: NPM dialog box that opens, specify the name of the run configuration, the npm command line command to execute, the scripts to run (use blank spaces as separators), the location of the package.json file to retrieve the definitions of the scripts from, and the command line arguments to execute the script with.
   Specify the location of the Node executable file and the Node.js-specific options to be passed to this executable file, see Node parameters for details.

Comment: I added the package.json file